# Should a std::random_device be kept alive after seeding a pseudo-random engine?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

The typical modern approach to get random numbers is like this:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 engine{rd()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{-10,10};

someInt = dis(engine);
```

I figure that the `std::random_device` object is only used once to seed the pseudo-random engine. I think therefore we can write this instead:

```
std::mt19937 engine{std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{-10,10};

someInt = dis(engine);
```

The later one does not keep the `std::random_device` object alive, and has the advantage of relieving the pain of coming up a name. But I find that a lot of examples on the Internet use the former version.

Is that a must, or are there reasons, to keep the `std::random_device` object alive and give it a name?

Answer (score 2):

You can see that the constructor of `std::mt19937` takes a single `result_type` argument, here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mersenne_twister_engine/mersenne_twister_engine/  That page also says that `result_type` is the first template argument, which for `std::mt19937` is `uint_fast32_t`.  This parameter is taken by value.

From the above, we can conclude that there is no (sane) way that the lifetime of the `random_device` must span the lifetime of the `engine`.  You're welcome to destroy the `random_device` as soon as you've extracted the seed from it.